# Movie-making script

Tags: python, windows, child-process, video

The purpose of making this code is to copy/paste and run it (and it should run).  I'm open to all feedback.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#   Author:     Nishith
#   Version:    1.0
#
#   Description:
#   A quicktime (part 2 ) generator from ready image sequence. User is 
#   prompted to this path. "First_part_of_image_sequence".mov is created 
#   in same folder
#
#   switch: 1 if works, 0 if does not work
#   variable names selected randomly
#   This script is as loosely coupled as possible. There can be more scope
#   of it being as would be seen as design pattern

import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import os,subprocess, re
import random
import tempfile
from types import *
import shutil
import unicodedata
import time
import ctypes

class makeQuicktime(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.fileExtension = ""
        self.backgroundImage = ""
        self.thumbnailImage = ""
        self.firstImage = ""
        self.tempFolder = ""
        self.symlinkFolder = ""
        self.oneImage = ""
        self.myTemp = ""

        self.elementName = ""
        self.qeName = ""
        self.date = ""
        self.imageSequence = ""
        self.lens = ""
        self.frameRange = ""
        self.notes = ""
        self.qnotes = ""
        self.currentFrame = ""
        self.imageregex = ""

        self.exepath = "D:/mayaslate/"
        self.ffmpeg = "ffmpeg.exe"
        self.composite = "composite.exe"
        self.dll = "vcomp100.dll"
        self.kerneldll = "kernel32.dll"

    def thirdpartyapp(self):
        """
            D:/mayaslate/ has 3 executables. if any is missing admin will put it
        """
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join (self.exepath ,self.ffmpeg)):
            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError("% app not present") % self.ffmpeg
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join (self.exepath ,self.composite)):
            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError("% app not present") % self.composite
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join (self.exepath ,self.dll)):
            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError("% app not present") % self.dll


    def setImageRegex(self,imageCountVar):                                                                                                                                  # check length of imageCountVar
        """
        @setImageRegex: padding image count.
        """ 
        if (len(imageCountVar) == 5):
            irx = "%05d"
        elif (len(imageCountVar) == 4):
            irx = "%04d"
        elif (len(imageCountVar) == 3):
            irx =  "%03d"
        elif (len(imageCountVar) == 2):
            irx = "%02d"
        elif (len(imageCountVar) == 1):
            irx = "%01d"
        return irx

    def firstImageCount(self,listOfFiles):
        """ 
        file list : @listOfFiles , parameter passed
        firstImageCount, returns what should be number on first image

        """ 
        whisper = ""
#       nc = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', listOfFiles[0].split('.')[1]).encode('ascii','ignore')
        nc = listOfFiles[0].split('.')[1]
        ic = str(int(nc) - 1)

        if ((len(nc) - len(ic)) == 0):
            whisper = ""
        elif ((len(nc) - len(ic)) == 1):
            whisper = "0"
        elif ((len(nc) - len(ic)) == 2):
            whisper = "00"
        elif ((len(nc) - len(ic)) == 3):
            whisper = "000"

        return (whisper + ic)

    def cleanDirectory(self,dName):
        for filen in os.listdir(dName):
            os.remove(dName.replace("\\","/") +"/"+filen)

    def makeTempFolder(self, fName):
        print 'fName : ',fName,'\n'
#       check tmp folder exst , if not flag message exit
#       sysTemp = tempfile.gettempdir().replace("\\","/")                                                                                                                   # get temp folder name
        sysTemp = "D:/mayaslate"                                                                                                                                            # get temp folder name
        if not os.path.exists(sysTemp):
            os.makedirs(sysTemp)
            mesg = "% now created " % (sysTemp)
            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayInfo(mesg)
            return 1
        else:
            self.myTemp = os.path.join(sysTemp,fName).replace("\\","/")
            if not os.path.exists(self.myTemp):                                                                                                                             # if already exists then clear it else create it
                os.makedirs(self.myTemp)
                print 'self.tempFolder : ',self.tempFolder,'\n'
            else:
                self.cleanDirectory(self.myTemp)
            self.tempFolder = self.myTemp               
            return 0        

    def selectFolder( self, folderName, fileType):
        fName = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', folderName).encode('ascii','ignore')
        if os.path.isdir(fName):
#           self.tempFolder = tempfile.gettempdir().replace("\\","/")                                                                                                   # get temp folder name
            self.tempFolder = "D:/mayaslate"                                                                                                                                            # get temp folder name          
            self.symlinkFolder = self.tempFolder + "/symlink/"                                                                                                          # create symlink folder within temp folder
            if not os.path.isdir(self.symlinkFolder):
                os.mkdir(self.symlinkFolder)
            print '%TEMP%',self.tempFolder,'\n'
#           for thumbnail
            temp_01 = os.listdir(fName)                                                                                                                         # get file name from user folder
            print 'temp_01 ',temp_01 ,'\n'
            sampleFileName = temp_01[random.randint(1,len(temp_01)-1)]                                                                                                  # select random image

#           fpof = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', (sampleFileName.split('.')[0])).encode('ascii','ignore')
            fpof = sampleFileName.split('.')[0]
            print 'fpof ',fpof ,'\n'
            retVal = self.makeTempFolder(sampleFileName.split(".")[0])                                                                                                  # make folder with file name in %TEMP%          
            if (retVal == 0):
#               self.fileExtension = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', sampleFileName.split('.')[2]).encode('ascii','ignore')
                self.fileExtension = sampleFileName.split('.')[2]
                print 'self.fileExtension : ',self.fileExtension,'\n'

                self.backgroundImage = self.tempFolder + "/background.jpg"

                self.thumbnailImage = self.tempFolder + "/thumbnail." + self.fileExtension

                temp_02 = fName + "/" + sampleFileName

                args = ["composite", "-compose", "Clear", "null:", temp_02, "-alpha", "Off", self.backgroundImage]

                process = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                ret = process.wait()
                if (ret == 0):

                    args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", temp_02 ,"-vf", "scale=iw/3.5:ih/3.5", "-frames:v", "1", self.thumbnailImage]

                    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                    ret = process.wait()
                    if (ret == 0):
                        print 'mate'

                        self.firstImage = self.tempFolder + "/firstImage." + self.fileExtension
                        self.thumbnailImage = self.thumbnailImage.replace(':', '\:')

                        temp_03 = "movie='%s' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]" % self.thumbnailImage
                        args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", self.backgroundImage , "-vf", temp_03 , self.firstImage]

                        process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        ret = process.wait()

                        if (ret == 0):

                            print 'pen penultimate'
                            oldid = os.listdir(fName)

                            if not isinstance(oldid,NoneType):

                                fiC = self.firstImageCount(oldid)
                                self.oneImage = fName + "/" + fpof + "." + fiC + "." + self.fileExtension
                                print 'self.oneImage : ',self.oneImage ,'\n'
#                               elementname and notes are gotten from user
                                self.date = (time.strftime("%d"+"\/ "+"%m"+"\/ "+"%Y"+" \- "+"%H"+"\:"+"%M"+"\:"+"%S"))
                                self.imageSequence = fpof

                                self.lens = str(int(cmds.getAttr('shotcamShape.focalLength')))                                                                                                      # get from globals
                                self.frameRange = (str(int(cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.startFrame'))) + " - " + str(int(cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.endFrame'))))                         # get from globals

                                args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", self.firstImage, "-vf", "[in]drawtext=fontsize=32:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='shotName':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-50,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Notes \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-90,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.qnotes +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-90,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Frame Range \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-130,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.frameRange +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-130,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Lens \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-170,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.lens +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-170,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Image Sequence \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-210,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.imageSequence +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-210,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Date \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-250,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.date +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-250,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Element Name \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-290,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='"+ self.qeName +"':x=((w)/5)+250:y=(h)-290,drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='FUTUREWORKS':x=130:y=200:fontsize=54:fontcolor=White[out]", self.oneImage ]

                                process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                                ret = process.wait()

                                if (ret == 0):                                                                                                                                  # "D:/imagesequence/dpx/brn_055.%04d.dpx"
                                    print 'penultimate\n'
                                    self.imageregex  = self.setImageRegex(sampleFileName.split('.')[1])

                                    newList = os.listdir(fName)                                                                                                         # get file name from user folder
                                    bunchOfPictures = self.symlinkFolder + fpof + "." + self.imageregex  + "." + self.fileExtension
                                    tempBunchOfPictures = self.tempFolder + "/" + fpof + "." + self.imageregex  + "." + self.fileExtension

                                    objSym = symlinkHouseKeep()
                                    objSym.createLink( newList , fName, self.symlinkFolder, self.fileExtension , fpof, self.imageregex)
#                                   print 'bunchOfPictures  : ',bunchOfPictures ,'\n'
#                                   print 'tempBunchOfPictures : ',tempBunchOfPictures ,'\n'
                                    cnt = 0
                                    for each in os.listdir(self.symlinkFolder):
                                        aaaa = self.symlinkFolder + "/" + each
                                        bbbb = self.tempFolder + "/" + each
                                        args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", aaaa  , "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='shotcam':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-35:fontsize=24:fontcolor=Yellow,drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Frame \:':x=(w)-600:y=(h)-35:fontsize=24:fontcolor=Yellow,drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='" + str(cnt) +"':x=(w)-300:y=(h)-35:fontsize=24:fontcolor=Yellow,drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Focal Length \:':x=(w)-600:y=(h)-65:fontsize=24:fontcolor=Yellow,drawtext=fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='" + self.lens +"':x=(w)-300:y=(h)-65:fontsize=24:fontcolor=Yellow", bbbb  ]
                                        process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                                        ret = process.wait()
                                        if (ret == 0):
                                            cnt = cnt + 1                                       
                                            continue
                                    print 'ultimate\n'
#************************************************************************************
# since the first image is going to be "0000" until ffmpeg takes any other, following line has the number hard coded to over overwrite 1st image from fname, it is without yellow labels                                    
#************************************************************************************
                                    shutil.copy(self.oneImage,(self.tempFolder + "/" + fpof + ".0000." + self.fileExtension) )
#************************************************************************************                                   
                                    quicktimeFile = fName + "/" + fpof + ".mov"

                                    args = ["ffmpeg", "-i", tempBunchOfPictures , "-vcodec", "png", "-pix_fmt", "rgb32", "-y", quicktimeFile]

                                    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                                    ret = process.wait()
                                    if (ret == 0):
                                        message = "completed quicktime : %s %s" % (quicktimeFile," ... deleting temp folder")
                                        OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayInfo(message)

                                    """
                                    clean up commands
                                    """                                     
                                    os.remove(self.oneImage)                                                                        # when running script perpetually, only first image number is constant delete this image once mov is created
                                    shutil.rmtree(self.myTemp)                                                                  
                                    shutil.rmtree(self.symlinkFolder)
                        else:
                            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayWarning("nothing in the folder")
        else:
            OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayWarning("Folder not existing. Create it then run this script")

#************************************************************************************
# userWindow
#************************************************************************************

    def userWindow(self):
        window = cmds.window( title="maya slate", iconName='ms', widthHeight=(200, 55) )
        cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
        cmds.text( label='Element Name' )
        self.elementName = cmds.optionMenuGrp( 'renderwith', label=' ', columnWidth=(2, 80) )
        cmds.menuItem( label='cones' )
        cmds.menuItem( label='rmcurves' )
        cmds.menuItem( label='mesh' )
        cmds.menuItem( label='headmesh' )
        cmds.text( label='Notes' )
        self.notes = cmds.scrollField( 'notes',editable=True, wordWrap=True, text='addtional info here...' )
        cmds.button( label='Close', command=('a.qeName  = cmds.optionMenuGrp( a.elementName , query=True, value=True )\na.qnotes = cmds.scrollField(a.notes , query = True, text = True)\ncmds.deleteUI(\"' + window + '\", window=True)\ncmds.fileBrowserDialog( m=4, fc=a.selectFolder, ft=\'directory\', an=\'Where should .mov reside in\')') )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.showWindow( window )

#************************************************************************************
# symlinkHouseKeep
#************************************************************************************
# type    : class 
# func    : createlink - create symbolic link of all files in folder
# listIm  : folderName
# fldr    : root folder name
# tmpfldr : sytem temp folder
# xtn     : file extension
# fpf     : first part of file
#************************************************************************************

class   symlinkHouseKeep(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.nwidth = ""
        self.number = 0
        self.kdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(a.kerneldll)

    def givenos(self, nwid , numbr):
        x = ""
        for i in range(0,nwid - len(numbr )):
            x = x + "0"
        return x + str(numbr)

    def createLink(self, listIm, fldr, tmpfldr, xtn, fpf,imx):
        npad = int(re.findall("\d+", imx)[0])
        count = 0
        for filename in listIm:
            inpt = os.path.join(tmpfldr,(fpf + "." + self.givenos(npad ,str(count)) + "." + xtn )).replace("\\","/")
            count = count + 1
            output = os.path.join(fldr, filename).replace("\\","/")
            print 'inpt / output ',inpt ,  ' / ', output ,'\n'
            self.kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA(inpt , output, 0)

a = makeQuicktime()

if  (cmds.file(query=True,sn=True,shn=True) == ""):
    OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError("file not saved/ either empty file or save file!")
else:
    a.userWindow()
```

Answer (score 6):

> **Disclaimer**: I haven't actually got to trying to run your code yet, this was all done by inspection. However, I think there's enough here to be getting on with...

## Style

Style is important; it makes your code easier to read and understand. Python [has a style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and (unless you're following a different one*) you should follow it, for example:

- your `import`s aren't laid out correctly (and you use a wildcard import from `types`, which isn't recommended, particularly as you only need `NoneType`);
- line lengths are well over 80 characters (particularly a problem when trying to read it here!);
- your function/method/variable names aren't `lowercase_with_underscores`; and
- your class names aren't `UppercaseWords`.

There is also a [guide to docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) (great to see some documentation, by the way!); single line docstrings should be on one line. There are more prescriptive styles, especially if you're using some kind of autodocumentation system (I like the [Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html)), but that sets out a good minimum.

At the very least, I would expect to tee the same style throughout, and the class and method docs to be *inside the classes and methods*, in terms of both position (just after `class`/`def` line) and indentation (same level as first line inside definition).

* *If you are following a different style guide, please mention which (and provide a link, if available).*

---

## Substance

Generally, you seem to have a lot of long, deeply-nested classes and methods. Try to refactor to keep each method short, shallow and single-purpose (see [the Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/); `import this`). Not everything has to be in a class, either...

I've put a few more specific issues below.

### `makeQuicktime`

This class seems to do a lot of things that aren't strictly related to its name. Consider moving all the folder-y stuff out into a separate class (or standalone functions).

#### `firstImageCount`

This seems to be one of several methods in your code that predominantly exists to deal with zero-padded numbers, and they all take different approaches. Write one, then call it from the others! You should get to grips with `str.format` and the other `str` methods, which will make this kind of padding much easier (and, I think, is clearer and less error-prone than `%` formatting).

*See also `makeQuicktime.setImageRegex`, `symlinkHouseKeep.givenos`.*

#### `makeTempFolder`

You defined `self.exepath = "D:/mayaslate/"` in `__init__`, then assign `sysTemp = "D:/mayaslate"` here. If you change the folder location, that's now two places you have to go looking for it (or, more likely, one place you'll find it and one place you'll forget it, causing bugs).

Rather than returning `0` or `1` use Python's booleans `True` and `False`.

#### `selectFolder`

This method is extremely long, and does things that aren't selecting a folder. This should be split out into a few separate methods with descriptive names.

This line:

```
if not isinstance(oldid,NoneType):
```

would normally be written:

```
if oldid is not None:
```

`None` is a singleton, it's appropriate to test by identity.

### `symlinkHouseKeep`

This is a much better example in terms of length and focus, aspire to this with your other class! The attribute and parameter names are a bit cryptic, though, particularly as the docstrings have disappeared.

### Running the script

The lines at the end of the script (`a = makeQuicktime()` onwards) would usually be guarded by:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

to prevent them from running when you aren't running the script directly (e.g. when you `import` it).

Comment: Note: the main reason why you would want to import your main program is for testing the functions.

Comment: @Davidmh not necessarily; on simple scripts I put the testing at the bottom then import for actual use. If you're implying that the OP should write some tests; absolutely!

Comment: I think this script is long enough so that the tests should not be in the main program because it would get too cluttered. My personal limit is around the size of the screen. And +1 to the tests! Anyway, that is besides the point; I just wanted to explain why one wants to be able to import your main program.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your code needs Windows to run, so I cannot execute it myself. jonrsharpe has done a pretty thorough analysis. Some complements:

**Creating strings**

In here:

```
def setImageRegex(self,imageCountVar): 
    """
    @setImageRegex: padding image count.
    """ 
    if (len(imageCountVar) == 5):
        irx = "%05d"
    elif (len(imageCountVar) == 4):
        irx = "%04d"
    elif (len(imageCountVar) == 3):
        irx =  "%03d"
    elif (len(imageCountVar) == 2):
        irx = "%02d"
    elif (len(imageCountVar) == 1):
        irx = "%01d"
    return irx
```

You are returning irx, but that may not be defined if `imageCountVar` is longer than 5 or empty. Also, you don't need to store it, you can just return it:

```
    if (len(imageCountVar) == 5):
        return "%05d"
    if (len(imageCountVar) == 4):
        return "%04d"
```

But that is pretty inefficient, as you are computing the length of something that is not changing several times in a row. So, you can do:

```
    _len = len(imageCountVar)
    if len == 5:   # Note you don't need parenthesis
       return "%05d"
    ...
```

But this is tedious and long. Be more clever! Just construct the string with that information

```
 def setImageRegex(self,imageCountVar):
    return '%0{}d'.format(len(imageCountVar))
```

You may or may not want to make sure it is in the [1, 5] range. And even if the strings were non trivial, you can shorten it like this:

```
 def setImageRegex(self,imageCountVar):
    return ['stringa_1', 'stringb_2', 'stringc_3'][len(imageCountVar) - 1]
```

The same trick you can apply when computing wisper:

```
wisper = '0' * (len(nc) - len(ic))
```

**Blank lines**

You use way too many blank lines. They should be used sparingly to divide logical blocks of the program. See for example:

```
            print 'self.fileExtension : ',self.fileExtension,'\n'

            self.backgroundImage = self.tempFolder + "/background.jpg"

            self.thumbnailImage = self.tempFolder + "/thumbnail." + self.fileExtension

            temp_02 = fName + "/" + sampleFileName
```

At first glance, before even reading it, I don't know what you are doing, but I cannot believe each one of the lines is so important and different than the others that deserves its own code block. And they are indeed not. You are artificially enlarging your code, and make its flow less readable. Here you have an even worse example:

```
            ret = process.wait()
            if (ret == 0):

                args = ["ffmpeg",...
```

I would have done exactly the other way around:

```
            ret = process.wait()

            if (ret == 0):
                args = ["ffmpeg",...
```

Or without the blank line whatsoever, depends. This takes me to another comment:

**Too many parenthesis**

Python does not require you to put parenthesis for the argument of `if`. It is much more readable to use:

```
          if ret == 0:
```

as there are less symbols cluttering the view.

**Comments**

You are putting the comment symbol in the first column. Without syntax highlighting it is very difficult to tell them apart, you should put them instead:

```
 # We are ready to do stuff:
do_stuff()
do_more_stuff()
cleanup()  # This is to tidy up
          ^ ^
          | L One space
          L At least two spaces, you can freely use more. See:

# Making an example up:
a = 1    # width parameter
b = 2    # length parameter
tau = 3  # time parameter
```

Also, you need more comments explaining the flow. Give a literary overview of what is going on there. There are never too many comments.